# how to manage/edit sqlite in hybrid apps

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework

Actually i'm new to hybrid app and i'm trying to make simple app using ionic with sqlite and i use google chrome console to log the app.
The question how  can i manage/edit sqlite database?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the functionality you would see in a native app can be invoked using cordova tools.

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/sqlite/

Try this plugin for a sqlite DB.

For temporary storage, you can use the localStorage of the browser.

Edit: I'm afraid I misread the question.  To manage the DB as you would in phpmyadmin, you can use command line or a GUI.

https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html
I have used this GUI before
http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/